# ndk-build compilation error in Cygwin

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying to build native code (mupdf) using ndk-build. I download android-sdk and android-ndk from http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

I also downloaded GnuWin32 using GetGnuWin32-0.6.3 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/getgnuwin32/

In Cygwin window, under the directory where my android project is at, I type: /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk/ndk-build

I get the following error messages:

> /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk/ndk-build: line 32: $'\r': command not found
>   /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk/ndk-build: line 41: cd: /cygdrive/c/Android/andr: No such file or directory
>   /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk/ndk-build: line 90: syntax error: unexpected end of file

However, in the file ndk-build, line 32 is an empty line.

I also tried to build from eclipse by following the steps in

http://mobilepearls.com/labs/ndk-builder-in-eclipse/

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

No luck on both with compiling the native code.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy paste the code from the web the compiler will not recognize the returns carriers. try to show the hidden characters or write again your code inside cygwin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I re-write the following lines in emacs: PROGDIR=`dirname $0`
PROGDIR=`cd $PROGDIR && pwd`
GNUMAKE='make'
GNUMAKE -f $PROGDIR/build/core/build-local.mk $@  
I get an error saying: /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk/ndk-build: line 4: GNUMAKE: command not found

Comment: I re-installed gcc from cygwin setup and now the make works fine. But I have another problem with setting up the path for src and destination file with ndk-build